# How to get SQL table property length attribute from SQL database tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I wonder if this is even possible, and I can't seem to find an answer. I am using Entity Framework / C# for a database application. I want to ensure that my front-end entities automatically match their counterparts in SQL for attributes like "StringLength". So, inside SQL, in my tables, if I specify, for example, "nvarchar(50)", I want to make sure that the user doesn't type more than 50 characters. I don't want to have to code this each time, so I'm looking for a way to have the C# application read the StringLength property from SQL and then apply logic in the front-end. I can't seem to find a way of getting this information by entity type/DbContext from the SQL database itself.

I thought I'd struck gold with this thread here: [How to get the maximum length of a string from an EDMX model in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024764/how-to-get-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-from-an-edmx-model-in-code) but this seems to read from the entity schema defined in the C# application, not SQL.

I have attached a .png of the info I am trying to get from SQL for clarification. Any advice would be appreciated:[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this query to return Maximum length of column *Description* in table *PaymentType*

```
SELECT
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'PaymentType' and COLUMN_NAME = 'Description'
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks. I didn't think of pulling it back through a SQL query. That should do the trick. I will test that out.